# WPF Tabcontrol access to a page within a frame

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs

I have a page with a frame inside a Tabcontrol.

How do I put a text (let's say, "Test") inside a Textbox control on a page that has been loaded in a frame inside a tab?

XAML:

```
<TabControl Name="tabDynamic" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="tabDynamic_SelectionChanged" Margin="0,23,0,0">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
            <DockPanel>
                <Button Name="btnDelete" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" Click="btnDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}">
                    <Image Source="Resources/delete.gif" Height="11" Width="11"></Image>
                </Button>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem }, Path=Header}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

which then loads a frame with a page:

```
private TabItem AddTabItem(string TabName)
{
    int count = _tabItems.Count;

    // create new tab item
    TabItem tab = new TabItem();

    tab.Header = TabName;
    tab.Name = string.Format("tab{0}", count);
    tab.HeaderTemplate = tabDynamic.FindResource("TabHeader") as DataTempte;

    tab.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(tab_MouseDoubleClick);

     // add controls to tab item, this case I added just a textbox
    Frame tabFrame = new Frame();
    AMSPage page1 = new AMSPage(TabName);
    tabFrame.Content = page1;
    tab.Content = tabFrame;

    // insert tab item right before the last (+) tab item
    _tabItems.Insert(count - 1, tab);

    return tab;
}
```

Now my users can switch between tabs but I have buttons in the window; lets say I press Button 1, and want to put "Test" in Textbox on any of the pages (Selected Tab).

Comment: "I have a page within a frame inside a Tabcontrol." and where is the code?

Comment: How about `OnLoad` Event?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is currently somewhat unclear. I suggest you [edit] it. Show us the code that you currently have - but only the relevant part, a [mcve]. Then explain to us how you are trying to add the text on the Textbox control. Tell us how you are trying to do this, what you expect to happen, and what is happening instead. With this kind of information, we may be able to help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I did and added more clarity; Thank you guys